# I have double yours

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know whether the following dialogue would be correct english:

"I have 2 litres of milk. How much do you have?" - 
"Double yours."

Is it okay to say "double yours" in this context?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I’d just call it a half-gallon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct.  **Double** is correct because your 2 liters of milk has been doubled, and **twice** is correct because the quantity of the milk is indeed an amount.

Answer (score 0):

One would usually say *twice yours*.